# Finding the leaves of an inductively-defined tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So, I have a function of type:

```
genTree :: Node -> [Nodes]
```

Given a node, this function generates the set of children of that node in a tree.  The function can be applied again to those children to generate their children, until it eventually generates a node with no children, i.e. a node for which genTree returns [].

What I'm trying to do is, given a starting node, generate the list of all leaf nodes in the tree that has it as the root.

Any advice?

Comment: btw. if you had represented the tree as a "ListT [] a" (ListT from List package) then "lastL" would give you the list of leaves

Comment: @yairchu: What do you think about http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right

Comment: @alexey_r: it's exactly the same thing, except it's not in Hackage, and doesn't come with commons list operations like takeWhile etc.

Comment: @yairchu: Would you care to explain that in more detail? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Resistor: with pleasure. see explanation in new answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function from Martijn's answer generates a list of all nodes in the tree. You can use this list and filter out the nodes without children to get the leaves:

```
nodes root  = root : concatMap nodes (genTree root)
leaves root = filter (null . genTree) (nodes root)
```

You can also combine these two functions into one to directly generate just a list of leaves, if you prefer:

```
leaves node
   | null children = [node]
   | otherwise     = concatMap leaves children
   where children = genTree node
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's generalize it a bit:

```
leaves :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]
leaves tree x = case (tree x) of
                  [] -> [x] 
                  -- the node x has no children and is therefore a leaf
                  xs -> concatMap (leaves tree) xs
                  -- otherwise get list of all leaves for each child and concatenate them
```

Applying static argument transformation (http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/888), we get

```
leaves :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]
leaves tree x = leaves' x where
  leaves' x = case (tree x) of
                [] -> [x] 
                xs -> concatMap leaves' xs
```

Use it as

```
leaves genTree root
```

or if you *really* want it to work only with `genTree`, inline it into the definition:

```
leaves1 root = case (genTree x) of
                 [] -> [x] 
                 xs -> concatMap leaves1 xs
```

which is morally equivalent to sth's second answer.

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't actually solve the problem I was looking for.

Comment: Yes it does, you just supply `genTree` as an argument. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

(not exactly an answer to the question, but related)

I like to represent trees of a as "`ListT [] a`". (`ListT` from the `List` package in hackage)

Then the answer for this question is just to use the function `lastL`.

"`Monad m => ListT m a`" is a monadic list containing "`a`"s, where trying to get the next list item (which may find out there is no such item) is a monadic action in "`m`".

A usage example for `ListT` - a program that reads numbers from the user until the user does not type a number and prints the sum of numbers after each input:

```
main =
  execute . joinM . fmap print .
  scanl (+) 0 .
  fmap (fst . head) .
  takeWhile (not . null) .
  fmap reads .
  joinM $ (repeat getLine :: ListT IO (IO String))
```

Where `repeat`, `scanl` and `takeWhile` are from `Data.List.Class`. They work both for regular lists and monadic lists.

```
joinM :: List l => l (ItemM l a) -> l a -- (l = ListT IO, ItemM l = IO)
execute :: List l => l a -> ItemM l () -- consume the whole list and run its actions
```

If you are familiar with Python, python iterators/generators are "`ListT IO`"s.

When using `[]` instead of `IO` as the monad of the monadic list, the result is a tree. Why? Imagine a list where getting the next item is an action in the list monad - the list monad means there are several options, therefore there are several "next items", which makes it a tree.

You can construct monadic lists either with higher-order functions (like the example above), or with `cons`, or with a python-generator notation (with `yield`) using the `GeneratorT` monad transformer from the `generator` package in hackage.

Disclaimer: `ListT` and `GeneratorT` are in no way widely used. I wrote those and I am not aware of any other users except for myself. There are several of users of equivalent `ListT`s, such as the one from the Haskell wiki, `NondetT`, and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
flatten node = node : concatMap flatten (genTree node)
```

Comment: this gives all the nodes, not just the leaves